# Setting up .ghci for Haskell installation in WSL

Tags: haskell

I used the `ghcup` tool to install `ghc` and `cabal`, on completion I tried to create a `.ghci` file to print a new prompt.

It gave me a warning

```
*** WARNING: .ghci is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
Suggested fix: execute 'chmod go-w .ghci'
```

*Even after doing the suggested fix the same warning appears and nothing happened to the prompt* :(

Comment: may you try doing `chmod 644 .ghci`

Comment: @elrmndo It did not work either. :(

Comment: I am having this problem using Nix on macOS 10.14.6 and 10.15.7 in early 2022. It is frankly embarrassing that this problem, which has been known for more than 8 years, has not been fixed.